# Designing a Formula?

Tags: connections

**QUESTION:**

> The half-life of a drug is the time it takes for a dose to reduce to
>   half its initial amount. A doctor prescribes a 4mg sleeping pill with
>   a half-life of 24 hours.
>
> Write down a formula connecting the mass, m, of drug remaining with
>   its half-life, t.

---

I know that is halves every $24$ hours however I'm not sure where to start except from.... $m = t$

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the quantity reduce to $1/2=2^{-1}$ in $24 $ hours  than the quantity  $m$ at $ h$ hours is:

$$
m=m_02^{-(\frac{h}{24})}
$$
where $m_0$ is the initial dose.